# Increase text size in Ubuntu 10.04 due to having large resolution/monitors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, resolution, accessibility

I have 24" dual monitors with 1920x1080 resolution on both of them. Consequently the text appears so small. I use the following text-intensive applications frequently:

- Web browser (Google Chrome)
- IDE (Komodo)
- Terminal (Gnome Terminal)
- Email (Thunderbird)

I can configure text size on IDE, Terminal and Email. But for Chrome, it is not a good idea to set proportional font size because often one wants to see the *entire* (not just proportional fonts) site to be zoomed.

So I am asking:

1. Is it possible to increase DPI in Ubuntu (much like on Windows) so as to increase the text size across all apps? OR
2. Is it possible to set permanent 'zoom' in Google Chrome, using a third-party extension maybe?

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 (**Lucid Lynx**)

Comment: as Ubuntu 10.04 is still in beta, i highly recommend asking this on the Ubuntu Forums.  any answers you get that solve the problem for the beta may not apply to the final release.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the DPI in the fonts settings. What you're looking for is: System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Fonts -> Details (it's a well-hidden button). My system is not in English so some disparities might occur.

Comment: I don't see a "Font" entry under System -> Preferences. I am using Ubuntu 10.4 (Lucid Lynx), by the way.

Comment: I don't know if you get notifications for edits to answers, but I edited my answer to contain the corrent "path".